# How to do parameterization of value appearing in the HTTP Request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to do parameterization for the value appearing in the name text of the HTTP Request of sample. Here is the value appearing in the request:

`https://104.40.86.162:9002/tiresearch/size/options?pageData={%22currentField%22:%22profile||tire%22,%22width||tire%22:%22235%22,%22profile||tire%22:%2240%22}`

How should I populate parameter value in the body of the sampler?

[Parameterization of value appearing in HTTP Header Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSoxQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) basically contains the following [JSON object](http://www.json.org/)

```
{
  "currentField": "profile||tire",
  "width||tire": "235",
  "profile||tire": "40"
}
```

Normally people use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to substitute hard-coded (or recorded) values with the values from external configuration file. If you don't care too much regarding your requests being repeatable, i.e. if it is fine to use random values you can use [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random)  to set `width||tire` and/or `profile||tire` parameters values.

For better readability I would recommend amending your HTTP Request sampler like:

[image: JMeter HTTP Request]

The above configuration will send a random number between 100 and 300 as `width|tire` each time the HTTP Request will be called. Similarly for variables originated from CSV files.

References:

- [JMeter: Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)
- [How to do Parameterization in JMeter using CSV?](http://blogs.quovantis.com/how-to-do-parameterization-in-jmeter-using-csv/)